# UIStepper not functioning in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

The code I have has no flaws and Xcode wasn't complaining until I tried to run it in the simulator and then tried to use the `UIStepper`, it popped up with an error saying `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var AgeSwitcherVar: UIStepper!  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func AgeSwitcher(sender: UIStepper) {
    label2.text = String(Int(sender.value))   
}
    @IBAction func SubmitButton(sender: AnyObject) {            
    if label2.text == "18"{
        label1.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        label1.text = "congradulations you passed the test"          
        }
}
}


import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

Comment: You probably forgot to hook the label in the interface to your `label2` outlet.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, there is `Signal SIGABRT` when you delete an outlet and put it back in without deleting the old one in the connection inspector (in the Interface Builder). If you go on the connections inspector and see a sort of exclamation point, delete it and put it back in and it should work fine. Here's an image:

[image]

It could also be that you forgot to connect one of the labels in the View controller to the Main Storyboard. This will be the case if you see an empty circle in the ViewController.